# How to group by day/month/year in CosmosDB SQL-API

Tags: python, sql, group-by, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to create a function able to group my data on Cosmos DB based on the day or the month or the year. I already have a performing command in pandas. I'd like to do the same.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
    {'date': '27/06/2020 12:49', 'labels': 0, 'code': 1},
    {'date': '27/06/2020 17:10', 'labels': 0, 'code': 3},
    {'date': '22/06/2020 09:02', 'labels': 0, 'code': 3},
    {'date': '22/06/2020 10:38', 'labels': 1, 'code': 1},
    {'date': '22/06/2020 21:50', 'labels': 1, 'code': 3},
    {'date': '25/06/2020 00:46', 'labels': 1, 'code': 1}
    ]
)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='D')).agg({'label':'sum', 'code':'count'})
```

[image]

I already tried different ways to do this in Cosmos, but the results are strange. Here's my query with the corresponding results:

```
'SELECT DateTimePart("D", r.data_ora_inserimento_preventivo), r.labels, r.sorgente_dati, count(1) FROM mycontainer r group by DateTimePart("D", r.data_ora_inserimento_preventivo), r.labels, r.sorgente_dati'

{'labels': 0, 'code': '3', '$2': 16236}
{'labels': 1, 'code': '3', '$2': 286}
{'labels': 0, 'code': '3', '$2': 16534}
{'labels': 1, 'code': '3', '$2': 187}
{'labels': 0, 'code': '3', '$2': 15726}
{'labels': 1, 'code': '3', '$2': 161}
{'labels': 0, 'code': '3', '$2': 15854}
{'labels': 1, 'code': '3', '$2': 177}
{'labels': 0, 'code': '3', '$2': 15405}
{'labels': 1, 'code': '3', '$2': 164}
{'labels': 0, 'code': '3', '$2': 15723}
{'labels': 1, 'code': '3', '$2': 304}
{'labels': 1, 'code': '3', '$2': 447}
{'labels': 0, 'code': '3', '$2': 3012}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DateTimePart will return undefined for the following reasons:
>
> The DateTimePart value specified is invalid
>
> The DateTime is not a valid ISO 8601 DateTime

Your date isn't a valid ISO 8601 DateTime which leads to strange results. So you need to cast your date to ISO format. You can achieve this by UDF. Then try something like this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    left(udf.casttoISO(c.date),10) as date, sum(c.labels) as labels, count(c.code) as code 
FROM c 
group by left(udf.casttoISO(c.date),10)
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-06-25",
        "labels": 1,
        "code": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-06-22",
        "labels": 2,
        "code": 3
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-06-27",
        "labels": 0,
        "code": 2
    }
]
```

BTW, `DateTimePart` function will not utilize the index, so I think `Left` function will be better.

---

**Update:**

1.You can create a UDF at Portal. About UDF, you can refer to this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-udfs).
[image]

2.Your comment mentions that you are using Python SDK. Unfortunately, when you run the above SQL, you will get the following error message:

> (BadRequest) Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: Query contains 1
> or more unsupported features. Upgrade your SDK to a version that does
> support the requested features: Query contained GroupBy, which the
> calling client does not support.

Because Python SDK doesn't support `Group BY` by now. They plan to add this feature this year. You can refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos#limitations). If you want to execute the above SQL, you can run it at Portal, using .NET SDK or JS SDK.

Comment: I tried your solution but I got this: `CosmosHttpResponseError: (BadRequest) Message: {"Errors":["The input user defined function 'casttoISO' is not present in the collection. Ensure to pass a valid function identifier."]}`.
Is it a problem of an uninstalled package or just a function that Cosmos doesn't hold?

Comment: @el_Rinaldo Have you created UDF in your collection?

Comment: I did installed pyspark. Does it include udf, doesn't it? This is the import: `from pyspark.sql.functions import udf`

Comment: @el_Rinaldo I update my answer, you can have a look.